# Why getNested() is a better approach?

Tags: javascript

There are two ways to achieve the same result:

- `this.question.validation.scoring_type !== 'exactMatch'`
- `_.getNested(this.get('question'), 'validation.scoring_type') !== 'exactMatch'`

the definition of `getNested` is:

```
getNested: function (object, attributeString) {
    if (object) {
        const split = attributeString.match(/(.+?)\.(.*)/);
        if (split) {
            return this.getNested(object[split[1]], split[2]);
        } else {
            return object[attributeString];
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach that involves getNested is more defensive, can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: The second one won't throw you a reference error, because you will never call an attribute on `null` or `undefined`. But it also does not allow you to pass dynamic parameters (variables as keys). You might want to look into optional chaining, a new feature of ES2020.

Comment: "*is more defensive*" - who claimed that without any explanation?

Comment: @Bergi, I directly quoted it from the comment on github before merging. I have not got time to talk to this colleague yet.